# How to solve Type Error occurred when creating object: Webkul\MpBlog\Block\Account\Navigation?

Tags: magento2, error, exception, object-manager, object

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Webkul\MpBlog\Block\Account\Navigation

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Webkul\MpBlog\Block\Account\Navigation

```
#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Webkul\MpBlog\Bl...', 'seller_mpblog', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure#0000000050651092000000005113cb26#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#00000000506515ef000000005113cb26#, 'seller_mpblog') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000050651516000000005113cb26#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000005065108a000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#0000000050651516000000005113cb26#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000005065108a000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('generateElements', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('generateElements', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...', 'core-session-dep...', 'customer-session...', 'catalog-session-...', 'persistent-sessi...', 'checkout-session...', 'tax-session-depe...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:39]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:39]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514dc000000005113cb26#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000506514de000000005113cb26#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: I have added \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager $objectManager, in constuct but no luck

Comment: Did you try with set:di:compile ?

Comment: Yes I have tried